# How to change border color of Semantic UI React Dropdown?

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I've successfully implemented the Semantic UI React Dropdown like this:

```
<div>
    <Form.Label>Search and Select Company</Form.Label>
    <Dropdown
        name='company'
        data-testid='companiesDropdown'
        placeholder='Ex. Goodyear'
        className={classes.errorState}
        fluid
        search
        searchInput={{autoFocus: true}}
        selection
        options={companies
                 ? companies.map((company, key) => {
                     return (
                        {key: key, value: company.company_id, text: company.company_name}
                       )})
                         : null}
        value={(companyId > 0) ? companyId: null}
        onChange={handleDropdownChange}
    />
    {determineErrorMessage('companyId')}
</div>
```

Now I'd like to change the border color if the element is in an error state such as the user hasn't picked an item yet.  To do this with any other HTML element, I can just set the `className` but it doesn't seem to work with this element.

In the example above, I'm just hardcoding the `className={classes.errorState}` where `errorState: { borderColor: 'red' }` but doing so doesn't work.

Any ideas on how to get this working properly?

P.S. As a temporary fix I added a `<div>` wrapper around it which kind of works except you can clearly see the border of the `<div>` and the border of the `<Dropdown>` element.

Answer (score 0):

HI i reworked the semantic example for you

As it's a div and not a true HTML list try it like this

**CSS**

```
 .dropdownRed {
     border: 1px solid red !important;
  }
```

**JSX**

```
 <Dropdown.Menu className={errClass}>
```

[Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-drop-down-red-fy62o) to working codesandbox demo

Comment: Thank you for all of that work!  Before I "perform surgery" on my code, I trust you saw that my Semantic UI Dropdown is being dynamically populated.  So I can't use your exact solution.

I can envision having a `<Dropdown ...>` element and `<Dropdown.Menu ...>` element.  Is there a third element underneath in which I could iterate through my `companies` array or should I just be instantiating `<Dropdown.Item ...>` elements like you've done?

Comment: @robertwerner-goodyear I would either add your items to the list like in an array map or just ditch the semantic DD and use the standard select

Comment: The reason I chose to use it is because I'm using its search/filter capabilities, which was a requirement of my previous ticket.  It seemed quicker to just use it than build such functionality myself.